# Saving upvote value to database (MEAN stack - reddit clone)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have been working on a reddit clone from the thinkster.io tutorial, and I can not figure out how to save upvote values to the database. Could some one please take a look?

// from angularApp.js

```
.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };

  o.upvote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      post.votes += 1;
    });
  };
  return o;
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
'auth',
function($scope, posts, auth){
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

  $scope.addPost = function(){
    //prevents empty posts
    if(($scope.title === '') || ($scope.body === '')) { return; }
    //creates post
    posts.create({
      title: $scope.title,
      votes: 0,
      createdOn: Date.now(),
      link: $scope.link,
      body: $scope.body,
    });
    //returns empty values after post is created
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
    $scope.body = '';
  };
  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post){
      posts.upvote(post);
  };
}])
```

//mongoose post schema

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
  body: String,
  createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  votes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  author: String
});

PostSchema.methods.upvote = function(cb) {
  this.votes += 1;
  this.save(cb);
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

// from index.js

```
// upvote a post
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, comment){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(comment);
  });
});
```

//from index.ejs (html)

```
   <i ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)" class="ion-chevron-up"></i><br>
     {{comment.votes}}<br>
```

Comment: What problem are you having? I can see there are 2 different urls, could this be the issue? One is `/posts/<id>/upvote` and the other is `/posts/<id>/comments/<id>/upvote`.

Comment: I accidentally pasted the wrong bit of Code. I just updated it.

Comment: And what is the problem you're having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I can't increase the upvotes. Nothing happens when I click. No error, no adjustment to the database, just nothing.

Comment: There are several things that could be going wrong here. When you click the button is the request being sent to your express app? You can verify this by checking the browser console or your express logs (console). If so, is it being routed to the correct router? You can verify by putting in some `console.log` before you try and save the upvote. If you find those things out it will be easier to help.

Comment: I'm getting a 401 unauthorized message. But I'm logged in, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed to add null to the return address.

Answer (score 0):

```
o.upvote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null, { ...
```